# Duplicates based on mutiple columns and date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been working on a query for identifying duplicates in my database, my requirement is - I need identify duplicates for the records that have a create date of sysdate-1 or a specific date. Is this feasible? 
The duplicates need to be identified based on multiple columns in multiple tables. for my eg below, I want to search for, I want to search for all dups for IDs with created date of 01-AUG-2017. Although 3&6 are also dups, they shouldn't show up in my result as the created date doesnt match. If I add the created date filter to my where condition, the query is dropping the match in the result.

T1

```
ID | V1 | V2 |CreatedDate   
---| ---  | ---     ----------  
1  |   A  |  US    01-AUG-2017  
2  |   B  |  FR    01-JAN-2017  
3  |   C  |  AU    25-SEP-2017  
4  |   B  |  FR    01-AUG-2017  
5  |   A  |  US    30-MAR-2016  
6  |   C  |  AU    14-JUN-2015
```

T2

```
ID | V3  
---| ---              
1  | Apple  
1  | Kiwi    
2  | Pear          
3  | Banana         
4  | Pear  
5  | Apple    
6  | Banana
```

T3

```
ID | V4     
---|  ---   
1  | Spinach  
1  | Beets  
2  | Celery  
3  | Radish  
4  | Celery  
5  | Spinach  
6  | Celery  
6  | Radish
```

Expected Output:

```
1 A US Apple Spinach  
5 A US Apple Spinach  
2 B FR Pear  Celery  
4 B FR Pear  Celery
```

My current query is along the lines of:

```
select V1, V2, V3, V4
from (select t1.id, t1.V1,t1.V2,t2.V3,t3.V4
      from t1, t2, t3
      where t1.id = t2.id and t1.id = t3.id
     )
group by V1, V2, V3, V4
having count(*)>1`
```

Comment: @mathguy can you elaborate pls?

Answer (score 0):

I thin the answer you are looking for is

```
select id,v1,v2,v3,v4  from 
  (select t1b.id,t1b.v1,t1b.v2,v3,v4,count(t1b.id) over (partition by t1b.v1,t1b.v2,v3,v4) cnt 
  from t1 t1a,t1 t1b,t2,t3
  where t1a.CreatedDate='01-AUG-2017'
  and t1a.v1=t1b.v1
  and t1a.v2=t1b.v2
  and t1b.id=t2.id
  and t1b.id=t3.id)
where cnt>1;
```

You have to use `self join` for your requirement and for duplicates yo need to use `ANALYTIC` function.

Comment: `01-AUG-2017` is not a date literal - it is a string literal. If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is does not match then the query will fail (and the user can set their own format in each session so the query could work for one user but not for another). Either use a date literal `DATE '2017-08-01'` or use `TO_DATE` with a format model (and appropriate NLS settings as the 3rd argument).

Comment: @MT0 : `DD-MON-YYYY` is the default date format in oracle. You don't need to use `TO_DATE` in this format. Oracle will auto Typecast it.

Comment: No, [the default datetime format template](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#CACFIJDC) is specified either explicitly with the initialization parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or implicitly with the initialization parameter `NLS_TERRITORY`. You can change the default datetime formats for your session with the `ALTER SESSION` statement. Install the database with a different locale and you will get a different default `NLS_TERRITORY`, run SQL Developer in a different country and it may default to a different date format. Do not assume a default format.

Comment: See [Date Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#g1012888) from the Oracle Documentation for some default date formats depending on the `NLS_TERRITORY`; the majority of the formats listed do not match your string literal.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/607ac2/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1( ID, V1, V2, CreatedDate ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'US', DATE '2017-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'FR', DATE '2017-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 'AU', DATE '2017-09-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B', 'FR', DATE '2017-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A', 'US', DATE '2016-03-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'C', 'AU', DATE '2015-06-14' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2( ID, V3 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 'Kiwi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Pear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Banana' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Pear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Banana' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T3( ID, V4 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Spinach' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Beets' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Celery' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Radish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Celery' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Spinach' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Celery' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Radish' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate
FROM   (
  SELECT T1.ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate,
         COUNT(*)
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct,
         COUNT( CASE CreatedDate WHEN DATE '2017-08-01' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_date_match
  FROM   T1
         INNER JOIN T2
         ON ( T1.ID = T2.ID )
         INNER JOIN T3
         ON ( T1.ID = T3.ID )
)
WHERE  ct > 1
AND    ct_date_match > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/607ac2/5/0)**:

```
| ID | V1 | V2 |    V3 |      V4 |          CREATEDDATE |
|----|----|----|-------|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |  A | US | Apple | Spinach | 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z |
|  5 |  A | US | Apple | Spinach | 2016-03-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 |  B | FR |  Pear |  Celery | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|  4 |  B | FR |  Pear |  Celery | 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Hi, I see that this query returns values that are not duplicates as well. For eg. if the date entered in the query is 01-MAR-2016 and there are no dups for that record, it still returns the original record. Is that right?

Comment: @Skn No, as per your requirements, it only returns rows that are duplicates (`ct > 1`) and where one of those duplicates matches your specified date (`ct_date_match > 0`).

Comment: this worked, thanks much. can you please explain how this works though, I want to be able to use this logic in future when needed? I am trying to understand how partition did this? My previous query was with group by.

Comment: @Skn You can find the documentation for analytic functions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). It just considers each set of rows with the same values in `V1`, `V2`, `V3` and `V4` (a partition) and `COUNT(*)` counts how many are in that set and `COUNT( CASE CreatedDate WHEN DATE '2017-08-01' THEN 1 END )` counts how many are in that set that match that date.

Comment: I am trying to further assign ranking to the duplicates found based on some additional conditions, can you help with that pls?